# python: join print with previous printed line

Tags: python

In python (2.6) is it possilbe to "join" print output with the previous line of print output? The trailing comma syntax (  `print x,`) doesn't work because most of the output *should* have a new line.

```
for fc in fcs:
    count = getCount(fc)
    print '%s records in %s' % ('{0:>9}'.format(count),fc)
    if count[0] == '0':
        delete(fc)
        print '==> %s removed' % (fc)
```

current console output:

```
     3875 records in Aaa
     3875 records in Bbb
        0 records in Ccc
==> Ccc removed
    68675 records in Ddd
```

desired result:

```
     3875 records in Aaa
     3875 records in Bbb
        0 records in Ccc ==> Ccc removed
    68675 records in Ddd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking if a print statement can remove the newline from the end of the previous line. The answer is no.

But you can write:

```
if count[0] == '0':
    removed = ' ==> %s removed' % (fc)
else:
    removed = ''
print '%s records in %s%s' % ('{0:>9}'.format(count), fc, removed)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("hello world")
```

print writes to the apps standard out and adds a newline.

However you sys.stdout is already a file object pointing to the same location and the write() function of a file object doesn't automatically append a newline to the output string so it should be exactly what you want.

Comment: You flipped your 'n' and 'o' in 'locatino'... or did you?

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
for fc in fcs:
    count = getCount(fc)
    print '%s records in %s' % ('{0:>9}'.format(count),fc),
    if count[0] == '0':
        delete(fc)
        print '==> %s removed' % (fc)
    else:
        print ''
```

There isn't a very good way to shorten that an maintain readability with the `delete()` in there.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. In code sample I'd left out the `delete(fc)` line, so your answer no longer works (I think?).

Comment: Oh you are absolutely right, I skimmed the question and was focusing on the printing aspect of it, sorry I will make an edit.

Comment: thanks Andrew. I accepted Tom's answer because I understood how it worked first. I appreciate knowing an alternate route to the same end.

Answer (score 1):

While Python 2 doesn’t have the feature you look for, Python 3 has.

so you can do

```
from __future__ import print_function

special_ending = '==> %s removed\n' % (fc)
ending = special_ending if special_case else "\n"

print('%s records in %s' % ('{0:>9}'.format(count),fc), end=ending)
```

Comment: thank you for giving a me look at what I'll need to do later on when I upgrade.

Comment: maybe not the best python code i’ve ever written, but i hope you get the idea :)